# Magento 1.9-How to put two input fields in the same row in the Customer form of adminportal

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.9

In Customer registration form,by default there is only one input field per row.

[image]

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Tab_Customer 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form 
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
protected function _prepareForm() 
 {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('customform_form', 
    array('legend' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Account information')));

$fieldset->addField('associate_to_website', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Associate to Website'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-select',
        'required' => true,
        'options' => array(0=>"Main Website", 1=>"Store Website"),
        'name' => 'associate_to_website'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('firstname', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('First Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-alphanum',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'firstname'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('lastname', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Last Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-alphanum',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'lastname'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('gender', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Gender'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-select',
        'required' => false,
        'options' => array(0=>"Male",1=>"Female"),
        'name' => 'gender'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Email'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'email'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('dateofbirth', 'date', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Date Of Birth'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-daterange',
        'required' => false,
        'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'name' => 'dateofbirth'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('taxnumber', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('Tax Number'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-alphanum',
        'required' => false,
        'name' => 'taxnumber'
    ));
$fieldset->addField('vatnumber', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('customform')->__('VAT Number'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-alphanum'
        'required' => false,
        'name' => 'vatnumber'
    ));     

    return parent::_prepareForm();
   }
}
```

In the Customer registration form of Magento 1.9 adminportal,by default there is only one field per row. Based on some references from similar forum sites, I tried many ways to put two input fields in a single row. But I couldn't able to do it.So if anyone is reading this blog please suggest me some answers on **'how to put two input fields per row in magento adminportal?'**.Thanks in advance......

Comment: use fieldsets and CSS